# Where is the menu to modify newly created objects?

Tags: mesh, objects, add-on, mathematics

So I've installed the Add Mesh: Extra Objects add-on because I want to make a mesh from a mathematical function.

However, the tutorial I'm following seems to use an old menu that I cannot find in the latest version. It looks like this :

[image]

How can I find this menu in the latest version of Blender. I'm new to Blender so any help would be appreciated.

Comment: That's the *Adjust Last Operation* panel.

Comment: Registered operators in versions 2.5x to 2.7x displayed their  details at the bottom of the toolbar (by default on the left)  as shown in question image. For 2.8 when you select add Z function surface from the menu it looks as pointed out in the duplicate.